# Prevent Nautilus from displaying thumbnails on a specific mount

Tags: nautilus, remote, thumbnails

I have written a filesystem over Fuse to access a remote pseudo-NAS (the French "Freebox V6", I'll soon publish it as GPL3... when it's a little bit more polished!).

The NAS is connected to a home ADSL, thus data comes down at the upload speed of ADSL, which is at best 1Mbps.

My mount works fine (read-only at the moment), but Nautilus sees the mountpoint (and all sub-directories) as a "local" filesystem and tries to make thumbnails.

As I have a directory full of images, this is quite horrible, because Nautilus then opens ALL the images to try to display the thumbnail.

I could switch the Nautilus preferences to "Never" for thumbnails, but then I'll loose thumbnails on my "real" local filesystem.

**So the question is:** with the preference "Only for local filesystem", how can I instruct Nautilus that my mountpoint is in fact **NOT** a local mount so that it will stop trying to draw thumbnails on that specific mount, but continue "thumbnailing" on mounts that are really local?

**Edit note:** *the same things happens if you use "standard worldwide" mounts such as sshfs, davfs,... as long as you mount over a relatively slow network (ADSL) and have images/movies on your mounted tree.*

Comment: Source code and binary (Lucid 64) for this filesystem [Beta] is now published : (http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=744561)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: You are right, as the question was initially worded. But in fact, as the anwser bellow proves, it affects ALL types of "network-mount", and not only my own development: sshfs, davfs,... 

As long a you mount these sort of mount over a slow network, the issue happens.

... and how do I "unflag"... (searching)...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this isn't currently possible - I've been searching for solutions with sshfs based mounts and been unable to find any.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have the same issue with davfs2 (and I assume we will have the same sort of issue with all "network" mounts).
I think I should "launchpad" a suggestion as there are more and more "cloud" storage and this issue is going to be more and more pregnant in the future!

Comment: This had better be a comment, it's not a solution