# Can Nautilus create thumbnails in separate directories for each mount point?

Tags: nautilus, external-hdd, remote, thumbnails

I've got some external and network drives and I have noticed that Nautilus keeps a single directory in ~/.cache/thumbnails which it uses to store thumbnails of these external drives right along with my local files.  I would really rather have each drive thumbnailed separately, preferably in a folder on that drive itself.  This would also keep the thumbnails in a central location, so that from a different machine the thumbnails would not need to be regenerated.

I found [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84453/prevent-nautilus-from-displaying-thumbnails-on-a-specific-mount) on preventing thumbnails from being created on specific mount points.  The answer on that question indicates that is not possible to do, as of over 8 years ago.  Right now I'm using a janky system where I manually move what the thumbnail folder points to (via a symlink) but this of course requires that I only try to access one file system at a time. Is it possible in 2020 to make Nautilus keep the thumbnails on the drive containing the actual files being thumbnailed?